# Only one method is working in my spring boot REST API application

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I create REST APIs using the spring boot framework. I used postgresql as the database. My database name is `tutor` and table is `student`. Created some REST APIs to maintain the crud operations. Some of them as follows

- `getAll` (method to get the all students)
- `getStudentById`(method to get the a students by id)
- `addStudent` (method to add a student)

create a controller class for this. (there are more methods). My prolem is, There is only one method is working properly. that is `getAll` method. But others are not working.

I will add the full code with classes.

**StudentController.java**

```
package com.codehub.tutor.core.controller;

import com.codehub.tutor.core.common.Validator;
import com.codehub.tutor.core.model.Student;
import com.codehub.tutor.core.service.api.StudentServiceAPI;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/students")
public class StudentController {
    @Autowired
    StudentServiceAPI service;

    @GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> getAll() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getAllStudent(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Student> getStudentById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getStudentById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Student> addStudent(Student student) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.addStudent(student), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Student> updateStudent(@PathVariable long id, Student student) {
        if (!Validator.isPositiveNumber(id) || student.getStudentId()!=id) new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.updateStudentById(student), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteStudent(@PathVariable("id")Long id) {
        service.deleteStudentById(id);
    }
}
```

**StudentServiceAPI.java**

```
package com.codehub.tutor.core.service.api;

import com.codehub.tutor.core.model.Student;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public interface StudentServiceAPI {

    /**
     * Get All students
     *
     * @return all registered students
     */
    List<Student> getAllStudent();

    /**
     * Get student by id
     * @param studentId selected student id
     * @return selected student
     */
    Student getStudentById(long studentId);

    /**
     * Delete student by id
     *
     * @param studentId student id
     * @return deleted
     */
    void deleteStudentById(Long studentId);

    /**
     * Update student by id
     *
     * @param student student
     * @return updated student
     */
    Student updateStudentById(Student student);

    /**
     * Add student
     *
     * @param student student
     * @return added student
     */
    Student addStudent(Student student);
}
```

**StudentServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.codehub.tutor.core.service.impl;

import com.codehub.tutor.core.dao.StudentDAO;
import com.codehub.tutor.core.model.Student;
import com.codehub.tutor.core.service.api.StudentServiceAPI;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentServiceAPI {
    @Autowired
    StudentDAO studentDAO;

    @Override
    public List<Student> getAllStudent() {
        return studentDAO.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Student getStudentById(long studentId) {
        return studentDAO.getById(studentId);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteStudentById(Long studentId) {
        studentDAO.deleteById(studentId);
    }

    @Override
    public Student updateStudentById(Student student) {
        return studentDAO.save(student);
    }

    @Override
    public Student addStudent(Student student) {
        return studentDAO.save(student);
    }
}
```

**Student.java**

```
package com.codehub.tutor.core.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long studentId;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Column(name = "parent_whats_app")
    private String parentWhatsAppNumber;
    @Column(name = "dob")
    private String dob;

    public long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getParentWhatsAppNumber() {
        return parentWhatsAppNumber;
    }

    public void setParentWhatsAppNumber(String parentWhatsAppNumber) {
        this.parentWhatsAppNumber = parentWhatsAppNumber;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
}
```

Seems connection is no problem. because getAll() method is working. anyway i will add the configuration file also.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tutor}
    username: ${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME:postgre}
    password: ${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD:mysecret}
  dbcp2:
    max-wait-millis: 30000
    validation-query: "SELECT 1"
    validation-query-timeout: 30
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    open-in-view: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
        id:
          new_generator_mappings: true
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: default
springdoc:
  pathsToMatch: /api/**
```

I will add screenshots also.

This is the student table structure.
[image]

This belong to the getAll method and it is working fine [image]

But this is belong o the getStudentById method and it is not working [image]

can you help me to solve this problem

Comment: You probably have an exception (and a stack trace) in your running service, look at that first and post it if you can't make sense of it.

Comment: There is no any exception like you mentioned

Comment: This could be because of datatype mismatch...you are using int  to collect the id and where as entity it's long. this is just guess. if possible pls share the log trace.